# Calling onDraw() method of a custom View in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a CustomView for Calendar. I have an onDraw method to draw the text in the calendar. I want to change the color of the day Text when i click on it. How can i achieve it?

CalendarView.java :

```
package com.example.calendar_module;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.MonthDisplayHelper;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CalendarView extends ImageView {

private static int WEEK_TOP_MARGIN = 0;
private static int WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = 05;
private static int CELL_WIDTH = 20;
private static int CELL_HEIGH = 20;
private static int CELL_MARGIN_TOP = 05;
private static int CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = 29;
private static float CELL_TEXT_SIZE;
private static int CALENDAR_WIDTH;
private static int CALENDAR_HEIGHT;

private static final String TAG = "CalendarView"; 
private String[] mDayString = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"};
private Calendar mRightNow = null;
private Drawable mWeekTitle = null;
private Cell mToday = null;
private Cell[][] mCells = new Cell[6][7];
private Cell[] mDayCells = new Cell[7];
private OnCellTouchListener mOnCellTouchListener = null;
MonthDisplayHelper mHelper;
Drawable mDecoration = null;

public interface OnCellTouchListener {
    public void onTouch(Cell cell);
}

public CalendarView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mDecoration = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.typeb_calendar_today);      
    initCalendarView();
}

private void initCalendarView() {

    mRightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    // prepare static vars

    Resources res = getResources();
    WEEK_TOP_MARGIN  = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.week_top_margin);
    WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.week_left_margin);

    CELL_WIDTH = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_width);
    CELL_HEIGH = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_heigh);
    CELL_MARGIN_TOP = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_margin_top);
    CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_margin_left);
   //       CALENDAR_HEIGHT = 700;
  //        CALENDAR_WIDTH = 700;
  //        
    CALENDAR_HEIGHT = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.calendar_height);
    CALENDAR_WIDTH = (int) res.getDimension(R.dimen.calendar_width);

    System.out.println("Width and Hight :"+CALENDAR_WIDTH+" "+CALENDAR_HEIGHT);
    System.out.println("Dimen Width and Height : "+R.dimen.calendar_width+" "+R.dimen.calendar_height);

    CELL_TEXT_SIZE = res.getDimension(R.dimen.cell_text_size);
    // set background
  //        setImageResource(R.drawable.background);
    mWeekTitle = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.calendar_week);

    mHelper = new MonthDisplayHelper(mRightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR), mRightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH));


}

private void initCells() {

    class _calendar {
        public int day;
        public boolean thisMonth;
        public _calendar(int d, boolean b) {
            day = d;
            thisMonth = b;
        }
        public _calendar(int d) {
            this(d, false);
        }
    };
    _calendar tmp[][] = new _calendar[6][7];

    for(int i=0; i<tmp.length; i++) {
        int n[] = mHelper.getDigitsForRow(i);
        for(int d=0; d<n.length; d++) {
            if(mHelper.isWithinCurrentMonth(i,d))
                tmp[i][d] = new _calendar(n[d], true);
            else
                tmp[i][d] = new _calendar(n[d]);

        }
    }

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    int thisDay = 0;
    mToday = null;
    if(mHelper.getYear()==today.get(Calendar.YEAR) && mHelper.getMonth()==today.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        thisDay = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }


    // build cells
    Rect Bound = new Rect(CELL_MARGIN_LEFT, CELL_MARGIN_TOP, CELL_WIDTH+CELL_MARGIN_LEFT, CELL_HEIGH+CELL_MARGIN_TOP);
   //       for( int i=0 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
   //       {
   //           
    //          mDayCells[i] = new Cell(mDayString[i],new Rect(Bound),CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
  //            Bound.offset(CELL_WIDTH, 0);
 //         
 //     }
 //     
 //     Bound.offset(0, CELL_HEIGH);      // move to next row and first column
 //     Bound.left = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT;
 //     Bound.right = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT+CELL_WIDTH;
 //     

    for(int week=0; week<mCells.length; week++) {
        for(int day=0; day<mCells[week].length; day++) 
        {

            if(tmp[week][day].thisMonth) {
                if(day==0 || day==6 )
                    mCells[week][day] = new RedCell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
                else 
                    mCells[week][day] = new Cell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
            } else {

                mCells[week][day] = new GrayCell(tmp[week][day].day, new Rect(Bound), CELL_TEXT_SIZE);
            }

            Bound.offset(CELL_WIDTH, 0); // move to next column 

            // get today
            if(tmp[week][day].day==thisDay && tmp[week][day].thisMonth) {
                mToday = mCells[week][day];
                mDecoration.setBounds(mToday.getBound());
            }
        }

        Bound.offset(0, CELL_HEIGH); // move to next row and first column
        Bound.left = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT;
        Bound.right = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT+CELL_WIDTH;

    }       
}

@Override
public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
  //        Rect re = getDrawable().getBounds();
  //        WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN = CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = (right-left - re.width()) / 2;
  //        mWeekTitle.setBounds(WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN, WEEK_TOP_MARGIN, WEEK_LEFT_MARGIN+mWeekTitle.getMinimumWidth(), WEEK_TOP_MARGIN+mWeekTitle.getMinimumHeight());

    initCells();
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    System.out.println("Width : "+CALENDAR_WIDTH);
    System.out.println("Height : "+CALENDAR_HEIGHT);
    setMeasuredDimension(CALENDAR_WIDTH, CALENDAR_HEIGHT);
  //        setMeasuredDimension(100,200);
}

public void setTimeInMillis(long milliseconds) {
    mRightNow.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
    initCells();
    this.invalidate();
}

public int getYear() {
    return mHelper.getYear();
}

public int getMonth() {
    return mHelper.getMonth();
}

public void nextMonth() {
    mHelper.nextMonth();
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public void previousMonth() {
    mHelper.previousMonth();
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public boolean firstDay(int day) {
    return day==1;
}

public boolean lastDay(int day) {
    return mHelper.getNumberOfDaysInMonth()==day;
}

public void goToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    mHelper = new MonthDisplayHelper(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    initCells();
    invalidate();
}

public Calendar getDate() {
    return mRightNow;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(mOnCellTouchListener!=null){
        for(Cell[] week : mCells) {
            for(Cell day : week) {
                if(day.hitTest((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                    mOnCellTouchListener.onTouch(day);
                }                       
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void setOnCellTouchListener(OnCellTouchListener p) {
    mOnCellTouchListener = p;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw background
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mWeekTitle.draw(canvas);

    // draw cells
    for(Cell[] week : mCells) {
        for(Cell day : week) {
            day.draw(canvas);           
        }
    }

    // draw today
    if(mDecoration!=null && mToday!=null) {
        mDecoration.draw(canvas);
    }
}



public class GrayCell extends Cell {
    public GrayCell(int dayOfMon, Rect rect, float s) {
        super(dayOfMon, rect, s);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }           
}

private class RedCell extends Cell {

    public RedCell(int dayOfMon, Rect rect, float s) {
        super(dayOfMon, rect, s);
        mPaint.setColor(0xdddd0000);
    }           

}


}
```

Cell.java :

```
  package com.example.calendar_module;

  import android.graphics.Canvas;
  import android.graphics.Paint;
  import android.graphics.Rect;
  import android.graphics.RectF;
  import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
  import android.util.Log;

  public class Cell {
private static final String TAG = "Cell";
protected Rect mBound = null;
protected int mDayOfMonth = 1;  // from 1 to 31
protected Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG
        |Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
int dx, dy;
protected String mDayString;
private Cell cell ;

public Cell(int dayOfMon, Rect rect, float textSize, boolean bold) {
    mDayOfMonth = dayOfMon;
    mBound = rect;
    mPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    if(bold) mPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);

    dx = (int) mPaint.measureText(String.valueOf(mDayOfMonth)) / 2;
    dy = (int) (-mPaint.ascent() + mPaint.descent()) / 2;
}

public Cell(String day,Rect rect,float textSize,boolean bold)
{
    mDayString = day;
    mBound = rect;
    mPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    if(bold) mPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);

    dx = (int) mPaint.measureText(String.valueOf(mDayString)) / 2;
    dy = (int) (-mPaint.ascent() + mPaint.descent()) / 2;

}

public Cell(String day , Rect rect , float textSize , int newColor)
{
    mDayString = day;
    mBound = rect;
    mPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
    mPaint.setColor(newColor);


    dx = (int) mPaint.measureText(String.valueOf(mDayString)) / 2;
    dy = (int) (-mPaint.ascent() + mPaint.descent()) / 2;
}

public Cell(int dayOfMon, Rect rect, float textSize) {
    this(dayOfMon, rect, textSize, false);
}
public Cell(String day,Rect rect,float textSize)
{
    this(day,rect,textSize,false);
}

protected void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(mDayOfMonth), mBound.centerX() - dx, mBound.centerY() + dy, mPaint);
}

public int getDayOfMonth() {
    return mDayOfMonth;
}

public boolean hitTest(int x, int y) {
    return mBound.contains(x, y); 
}

public Rect getBound() {
    return mBound;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(mDayOfMonth)+"("+mBound.toString()+")";
}




}
```

CalendarActivity.java

```
package com.example.calendar_module;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import com.example.calendar_module.CalendarView.OnCellTouchListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CalendarActivity extends Activity{

public static final String MIME_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.calendar_module.date";
public static String mClickedDate, mClickedMonth;
CalendarView mView = null;
TextView mHit;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private  Button mNextButton;
private Button mPreviousButton;
private TextView mMonthText ;
private int mMonthInt;
private ListView mEventListView;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mView = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    mEventListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.EventsList);
    mEventListView.setAdapter(new BadgeAdapter(this));

    mView.setOnCellTouchListener(new OnCellTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTouch(Cell cell) {

            TextView mMonthText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MonthText);
            mClickedDate = ""+cell.getDayOfMonth();
            mClickedMonth =""+mMonthText.getText();
 //             System.out.println("Clicked date is : "+mClickedDate+" "+mClickedMonth);
 //             startActivity(new Intent(CalendarActivity.this,Event.class));

 //             cell = new Cell(cell.getDayOfMonth(),new Rect(cell.getBound()),Color.MAGENTA);

        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextMonth);
    mPreviousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PreviousMonth);
    mMonthText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MonthText);

    mMonthText.setText(DateUtils.getMonthString(mView.getMonth(), DateUtils.LENGTH_LONG)+", "+mView.getYear());

 //        System.out.println("CurrentMonth is : "+mView.getMonth());

 //        if(getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PICK))
 //         findViewById(R.id.hint).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mView.nextMonth();
            mMonthText.setText(DateUtils.getMonthString(mView.getMonth(), DateUtils.LENGTH_LONG)+", "+mView.getYear());

        }
    });

    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mView.previousMonth();
            mMonthText.setText(DateUtils.getMonthString(mView.getMonth(), DateUtils.LENGTH_LONG)+", "+mView.getYear());
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Calendar View Height : "+mView.getHeight());

}



private class RedCell extends Cell {

    public RedCell(Cell cell) {
        super(cell.getDayOfMonth(),new Rect(cell.getBound()), R.dimen.cell_text_size);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);


    }           

  }




}
```

Answer (score 39):

Call `mView.invalidate();` in your onClick() method for that View. This will call `onDraw()` (eventually), which will then run the drawing code for your view.

Comment: This will allow you to also invoke onDraw() of the view in the main activity. Just find the activity by its id and then modify some variables and then call onDraw which will allow the canvas to utilize those modified variables.